Can you omit から directly connecting plain forms?
During a conversation with a native, I used the following sentence

試験があるから１月の第3週を待っています。

To mean "Since there is an exam, I'm waiting for the 3rd week of January".
My sentence was corrected to

試験がある １月の第3週を待っています。

Which, according to the other person, sounds more natural. Now, I'm bewildered by the connection of the plain form 「ある」to 「待っています」. The other person explained that 「から」or 「ので」can sometimes sound too strong, as if pinpointing the reason and it's usual to omit them. I have never heard of this and at the very least, if I had to directly connect the verbs, I would use the ~て form, that is:

試験があって １月の第3週を待っています。

So, I've heard about omitting particles in Japanese, but never about cases like this. I'm only just a beginner, though.
Would you please explain to me what is going on? Is there possibly a misunderstanding with what I thought I was saying?

This “ある” is simply a relative clause. It's not an independent sentence.
It just means “I'm waiting for the third week of January, when I have an exam.”
As in it modifies “1月の第3周”.
This is in general by the way something Japanese often does, using relative clauses to indicate cause and effect where English would use a separate clause, for instance:

“俺を裏切ったお前を許さない！” -> “I won't let you get away with betraying me!”

Using “I won't let you, who betrayed me, get away with it.” is grammatical in English, but unnatural.

Oooh, I see! I haven't studied relative clauses yet. I could feel that it was all related to the role played by １月の第3週, but it made no grammatical sense with my current level. I have to get used to it, because as you said it feels unnatural to me as a foreign learner. The most difficult thing is not accepting what is more natural, rather get used to other grammatical sentences like mine being unnatural.

@Mr.Feynman I honestly think it's impressive that you can make a correct sentence like that, including knowing that “〜が” is definitely the way to go here not “〜は” before you've used relative clauses. Also in my opinion “〜から” is completely fine here as well though I guess the relative clause is slightly better but it feels very nitpicky to me at least, but I'm nowhere near native level.

Thank you. Regarding が vs は it's still a hot topic that I have a lot to learn about, of course, as I've been studying for about two months, but maybe my book has just a weird order (e.g. the first volume, which covers most of N5 introduces the て form at the end), so I'm still at the stage where I get it right thanks to examples or minor caveat, but without a solid understanding than just "different subjects" and "the exam is a new information".
